# ajax post returns Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"}

Tags: ajax, .post

I have a json string with me {offer.offer.offerId.USSellerId: {$gt: 50}}. All i wanted to do was to call a POST REST Service with this json query as payload and get the returned JSON.

I was able to call that service using chrome advanced rest client and I get the data back. But my problem is when I tried to call this service using below line of code  I get the following errors

```
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://10.242.172.12:8080/cqs/services/services/cqs/search",
        Accept: "application/json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: {"offer.offer.offerId.USSellerId": {"$gt": 50}},
        async:true,
        crossDomain: true,
        always: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log(data)
         console.log(textStatus)
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data, status, err) {
            console.log(data)
            console.log(status)
            console.log(err)
        }
    });
```

I see the following in the console:

Object { readyState=0, status=0, statusText="error"}
error
emptry string..

I could not understand anything from this error. When i did google this error, many suggestion tell that it could be cross browser problem. I have no control over server side code.

How can i fix that cross browser error from client side?

Comment: Have you checked the `content-type` http header? If you actually are sending json data, you should specify the correct `contentType` in `ajax` settings, cause jQuery uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as default content type, see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Hi IIya, I changed my jquery post to ajax, but this time i get a weird error back which does not have anything useful to say :(

Comment: Most likely your request doesn't even get sent now. Two things - wrap your data object in `JSON.stringify()` and look for errors in console.

Comment: Thanks IIya. Though i could not fix this, I was able to see  in the console that it is because of cross domain issue. I have asked the owner of the service to fix this..

Answer (score 3):

Please check the [XMLHttpRequests being stopped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest):

> If you end up with an XMLHttpRequest having **status=0** and
>   statusText=null, it means that the request was not allowed to be
>   performed. It was UNSENT. A likely cause for this is when the
>   XMLHttpRequest origin (at the creation of the XMLHttpRequest) has
>   changed when the XMLHttpRequest is then open(). This case can happen
>   for example when one has an **XMLHttpRequest that gets fired on an
>   onunload event for a window**: the XMLHttpRequest gets in fact created
>   when the window to be closed is still there, and then the request is
>   sent (ie open()) when this window has lost its focus and potentially
>   different window has gained focus. The way to avoid this problem is to
>   set a listener on the new window "activate" event that gets set when
>   the old window has its "unload" event fired.