# jQuery AJAX doesn't work in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I've got a problem with making a AJAX request on my website (not crossdomain).

This is the code I am using:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
        var nameW = $("#name").val();
        var teamValue = $("#team").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/smoke/add.php",
            data: {
                    name:nameW,
                    team:teamValue,
                    firstX:firstposition[2],
                    firstY:firstposition[3],
                    secondX:secondposition[2],
                    secondY:secondposition[3]
                },
            success: function(response) {  console.log("Response: " + response)   },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                        console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
  });
```

It does work in Google Chrome, but not in FireFox. So I think there is something wrong with my ajax request.

Comment: do you get an error in your log?

Comment: Not at all:  {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
javascript.js (regel 54)
AJAX error: error : - Not an useful error anyways

Comment: Also i can't see which function you are accessing in your add.php? I don't now much about php but don't you have to define a method to call in your ajaxcall?

Comment: @Mivaweb Nope, it can be a scriptlet

Comment: And can you add some sort of breakpoint in your add.php to catch the call and see whats in it? Maybe someting wrong with your data your processing?

Comment: Possibly related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818224/ajax-post-returns-object-readystate-0-status-0-statustext-error

Comment: @Mivaweb What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @top97 in your add.php where you do stuff during the call add some logging to see what exaclty is happening

Comment: @Mivaweb When I add print_r($_POST); logging to a file, it just returns "1".

Comment: @top97 the last thing I can suggest is using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). With this you can view the request and response of your ajax call

Comment: @Mivaweb http://pastebin.com/ruZTsRih This is what I am getting in my console on FireFox;

Comment: @top97 I see the link in the call is `http://localhost/smoke/` where `add.php` is missing....

Comment: @Mivaweb http://localhost/smoke/add.php does exist. The thing is, it does work in Google Chrome.

Comment: I've never seen `"status":0,` without a more useful error message in the JavaScript console. Look there (above where you are outputting stuff with console.log statements).

Comment: @Quentin This is all I am getting:    "{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}" javascript.js:54:0
"AJAX error: error : " javascript.js:55:24
POST http://localhost/smoke/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]

Comment: possible duplicate of [$.ajax post working in Chrome, but not in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274383/ajax-post-working-in-chrome-but-not-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2):

You did not cancel the submit/click action so the page is posting back to the server and cancelling the request. You need to prevent default.

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
```